# Apache POI: separate logic for xls and xlsx?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm looking at Apache POI to parse some Excel files. What I could see so far is that there are HSSF* classes to deal with xls and XSSF* for xlsx files.
I need to read some rather complicated data pattern from the first sheet of a workbook.

So the question is: do I have to code the same logic twice for both xls and xlsx formats or can I work with both in a more universal way?

Comment: Shouldn't there be interfaces for *everything* in POI?

Comment: @heikkim, Yep, you're right. Now that I've looked through javadoc, I see it. Was confused by examples I googled up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use interfaces that are abundant in POI. For example the **Sheet** interface has many implementors, including *HSSFSheet* and *XSSFSheet*.

Answer (score 1):

There are also org.apache.poi.ss classes which can deal with both formats. But you need to modify your code a little bit.

Take a look here:

```
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html
```

Comment: Yes, these are the interfaces mentioned in @heikkim's answer, thanks.